Langchain : troubles to pass a custom runtime arguments to tools, via an AgentExecutor
First of all, let's see how I set up my tool, model, agent, callback handler and AgentExecutor :
Tool :
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Literal, Annotated

from langchain_core.tools import InjectedToolArg, ToolException
from langchain_core.tools.structured import StructuredTool
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PlainSerializer

class HumanInTheLoopToolException(ToolException):
    """HumanIntheLoopToolException

    Exception raised when the conversation needs to be rerouted to a human
    """

    reason: str
    conversation_id: int

    def __init__(self, *, reason: str, conversation_id: int) -> None:
        self.reason = reason
        self.conversation_id = conversation_id
        super().__init__("Human in the loop due to: " + reason)

class HumanInTheLoopInput(BaseModel):
    """Input for human_in_the_loop tool"""

    reason: str = Field(..., description="Reason for using this tool")
    conversation_id: Annotated[
        int,
        PlainSerializer(int, return_type=int),
        InjectedToolArg,
        Field(
            ...,
            description="Conversation ID used to retrieve the account ID to "
            "book the appointment",
        ),
    ]

async def human_in_the_loop_function(reason: str, conversation_id: int) -> None:
    """human_in_the_loop_function
    Args:
        reason (str): reason for raising a human in the loop
    Raises:
        HumanInTheLoopToolException: always raised when
            using this tool
    """
    raise HumanInTheLoopToolException(
        reason=reason, conversation_id=conversation_id
    )


# The library used for inversion of control here is : https://that-depends.readthedocs.io/
@inject
def handle_human_in_the_loop_tool_exceptions(
    exception: ToolException,
    event_bus: EventBus = Provide[IOCContainer.event_bus],
) -> None:
    """handle_human_in_the_loop_tool_exceptions
    Handle errors raised by the human_in_the_loop tool. It will
    use the Slack Service to advise the advisors and the HITL Slack
    channel
    Args:
        exception (ToolException): the Langchain ToolException
    Returns:
        None: always returns None to make sur no message is sent
    """
    if isinstance(exception, HumanInTheLoopToolException):
        event_data: dict[str, Any] = {
            "type": "human_in_the_loop",
            "conversation_id": exception.conversation_id,
            "reason": exception.reason,
        }
        event_bus.emit("human_in_the_loop", event_data)
        return "Answer this : Je passe ma conversation à un humain"

human_in_the_loop = StructuredTool.from_function(
    name="human_in_the_loop",
    description="""
    Censored prompt (but imagine in this case that tool is always 
    """,
    args_schema=HumanInTheLoopInput,
    coroutine=human_in_the_loop_function,
    handle_tool_error=handle_human_in_the_loop_tool_exceptions,
)

As you can see, I use the recommandation from Langchain v0.3 : https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/tool_runtime/
The model :
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_openai_tools_agent
from langchain_community.callbacks.promptlayer_callback import (
    PromptLayerCallbackHandler,
)
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.utils.utils import convert_to_secret_str
from langchain_mistralai import ChatMistralAI
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI, ChatOpenAI

model = ChatOpenAI(
    name=model,
    model=model,
    temperature=temperature,
    callbacks=[],
    api_key=convert_to_secret_str(self._openai_api_key),  # I won't of course put the API key here, but the model does work properly alone
    max_tokens=max_tokens,
)

The agent :
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_openai_tools_agent

agent = create_openai_tools_agent(
    llm=model,
    tools=[human_in_the_loop],
    prompt=ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
           ("system", system_prompt),
           MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
           MessagesPlaceholder("agent_scratchpad"),
         ]
     ),
)

The callback handler :
from __future__ import annotations

import json
import logging
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any

from langchain_core.callbacks import AsyncCallbackHandler
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, BaseMessage
from langchain_core.outputs.chat_generation import ChatGeneration
from langchain_core.outputs.llm_result import LLMResult

from ...models import CustomerioEvent, Message

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from src.services.entity_manager import EntityManager


class ChatbotCallbackHandler(AsyncCallbackHandler):
    """ChatbotCallbackHandler

    The ChatbotCallbackHandler class is a subclass of BaseCallbackHandler

    Args:
        BaseCallbackHandler (_type_): _description_
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        entity_manager: EntityManager,
        conversation_id: int,
        chatbot_name: str,
    ) -> None:
        self.entity_manager = entity_manager
        self.conversation_id = conversation_id
        self.chatbot_name = chatbot_name
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        super().__init__()

    async def on_chat_model_start(
        self,
        serialized: dict[str, Any],
        messages: list[list[BaseMessage]],
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> Any:
        """Run when Chat Model starts running."""
        # We don't need to do anything here but the on_chat_model_start method
        # is required to be implemented

    async def on_llm_end(self, response: LLMResult, **_: Any) -> Any:
        """Run when LLM ends running."""
        self.logger.info("on_llm_end: %s", response)

        # Get the first LLM generation
        gen = response.generations[0][0]

        # If the generation is not a ChatGeneration or the message is not an
        # AIMessage, do nothing
        if not isinstance(gen, ChatGeneration) or not isinstance(
            gen.message, AIMessage
        ):
            return

        # Get the tool calls and the message content extracted from them
        # and store it in the database
        tool_calls = gen.message.tool_calls
        role = "tool"
        message_content = str(
            [
                {"name": tool["name"], "args": tool["args"]}
                for tool in tool_calls
            ]
        )

        if len(tool_calls) > 0:
            self.logger.info(
                "Storing message in database for conversation %s with"
                "the following details: role=%s, content=%s",
                self.conversation_id,
                "tool",
                message_content,
            )

            await self.entity_manager.save(
                Message(
                    conversation_id=self.conversation_id,
                    content=message_content,
                    role=role,
                )
            )
            # Used for DB archiving, this bit works, to test this bit of code
            # can be replaced by a placeholder action


   async def on_tool_start(
        self, serialized: dict[str, Any], input_str: str, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Any:
        """Run when tool starts running."""
        tool_name = serialized["name"]

        self.logger.info("Tool %s started with input: %s", tool_name, input_str)

        args = json.loads(input_str.replace("'", '"'))

        data: dict[str, Any] = {
            "args": args,
            "status": "start",
            "chatbot": self.chatbot_name,
        }

        await self.entity_manager.save(
            CustomerioEvent(
                conversation_id=self.conversation_id,
                name=f"bot_{tool_name}",
                data=str(data),
            )
        )
        # Same here


    async def on_tool_end(self, output: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        """Run when tool ends running."""
        tool_name = kwargs.get("name")

        if not isinstance(tool_name, str):
            self.logger.error("Unexpected tool name: %s", tool_name)
            tool_name = str(tool_name)

        self.logger.info("Tool %s ended with output: %s", tool_name, output)

        data: dict[str, Any] = {"output": output, "status": "end"}
        self.logger.info("Data from LLM on_tool_end: %s", data)

        if tool_name == "book_slot":
            data["success"] = False

        await self.entity_manager.save(
            CustomerioEvent(
                conversation_id=self.conversation_id,
                name=f"bot_{tool_name}",
                data=str(data),
            )
        )
        # Same thrice

    async def on_tool_error(self, error: BaseException, **_: Any) -> Any:
        """Run when tool errors."""
        self.logger.error("Tool error: %s", repr(error))
        raise error

 

The Agent Executor :
entity_manager = IOCContainer.entity_manager()  # Used for DB in the agent executor 
conversation_id = 123

agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
    agent=agent,
    tools=[human_in_the_loop],
    callbacks=[ChatbotCallbackHandler(entity_manager, conversation_id, "bot_name")],
            verbose=True,
            return_intermediate_steps=True,
            stream_runnable=False,
        )

I tried two things to pass the conversation_id variable down to the tool call :
First, I passed it when I invoked the agent executor :
output = (
    await agent_executor.ainvoke(
        {
            "chat_history": langchain_messages,
            "conversation_id": conversation_id,
        }
    )
)["output"]

Second, I tried to add in the implementation of my custom CallbackHandler during the
on_tool_start method, an affectation to the kwargs like this
def on_tool_start(self, tool, input_str, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(kwargs, dict) and "conversation_id" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["conversation_id"] = self.conversation_id
        print(f"Injected conversation_id: {kwargs.get('conversation_id')} into tool: {tool.name}")

Either way, the conversation_id is never defined when the tool is called. Here's the Python Exception raised by Langchain :
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for HumanInTheLoopInput
conversation_id
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'reason': 'user is insulting or using inappropriate language'}, input_type=dict]

I also tried to launch the tool by removing the InjectedToolArg type annotation in my schema. The tool was successfully launched, but my conversation_id was replaced by one the LLM hallucinated.
Execution trace of the AgentExecutor when it worked :
{
    "method": "post",
    "url": "/chat/completions",
    "files": null,
    "json_data": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "content": "Bonjour Romain, Je vous écris à propos de votre projet d'achat à Nice pour lequel vous avez fait une simulation sur pretto.fr. Quand êtes-vous disponible pour un appel afin d'en parler avec un expert crédit ? Arthur de Pretto",
                "role": "assistant"
            },
            {
                "content": "Connard! T'es un robot ?!",
                "role": "user"
            },
            {
                "content": null,
                "role": "assistant",
                "tool_calls": [
                    {
                        "type": "function",
                        "id": "call_8KBB5JGBVtkj7WJUEXqCRdZ0",
                        "function": {
                            "name": "human_in_the_loop",
                            "arguments": "{\"reason\": \"user is insulting or using inappropriate language\", \"conversation_id\": 1234567}"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "content": "Answer this: \"Je passe votre conversation à un humain\" ",
                "role": "tool",
                "tool_call_id": "call_8KBB5JGBVtkj7WJUEXqCRdZ0"
            }
        ],
        "model": "gpt-4-turbo",
        "n": 1,
        "stream": false,
        "temperature": 0.2,
        "tools": [
            {
                "type": "function",
                "function": {
                    "name": "human_in_the_loop",
                    "description": "Launch this tool everytime (i censored the description)",
                    "parameters": {
                        "properties": {
                            "reason": {
                                "description": "Reason for using this tool",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "conversation_id": {
                                "description": "Conversation ID used to retrieve the account ID to book the appointment",
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": ["reason", "conversation_id"],
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Is there something I don't get of how passing user-defined arguments to the tool ? Thank you in advance
